# How to translate matrix from one side of an equation to the other?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I was wondering how to translate matrix from one side of an $=$ to the other and if the following was the right way to do it, that is to say add a transposed of the matrix on one side to cancel it and send the same transposed matrix to the other side of the equation:

\begin{align*}
&V\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}\\
&\Leftrightarrow V\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 &1\end{pmatrix} = x
\end{align*}

Because in my casio 35 + calculator this creates a $3\times 3$ matrix whereas it should have been a single value as far as I am looking for eigen values.

Comment: What is $V$ in this question? In general, it makes no sense to "translate matrix from one side to the other". You have to understand what the equation means before you can plug numbers into a calculator.

Comment: This operation is not allowed, if you want to solve for $x$, you will actually need to solve the eigenvalue problem $V u = x u$, which for a 3x3 matrix is not that difficult